# How to prevent the remove of a certain folder in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gitlab-ci, bucket

I'm working in the deploy of some files to a Bucket in Google Cloud via Gitlab CI. The command that i'm using to remove the objects is `gsutil -m rm gs://pr.homefront.com`

That command removes everything from the bucket, but i would like to change it to still removing everything except a folder named "ibw" inside of that bucket every single time the command runs.

Answer (score 2):

You can add [temporary holds](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/holding-objects#use-object-holds) to your objects within a folder, this holds prevent the manipulation or deletion over this objects

You can apply the holds via the following gsutil command:

```sh
gsutil -m  retention temp set  gs://bucketname/ibw/*******
```

* *each asterisk is a folder level*

you can set the holds before rm command and unset these after the rm command. The objects cannot be modified or removed until the hold is removed

UPDATE:

It is possible to add holds to empty folders

1. I created an empty folder via Cloud console
2. I run the following commands to avoid remove the empty folder

```sh
#this block the empty folder, if this is an folder with files all files will be blocked
gsutil -m  retention temp set  gs://bucketname/ibw/*******

#this operation can't remove objects,and empty folders with holds
gsutil -m rm gs://bucketname

#remove the hold of the empty folder, if this is an folder with files all files will be released
gsutil -m  retention temp release  gs://bucketname/ibw/*******
```

Comment: The "set" retention prevents from deleting while removing?

Comment: @CristianBlanco yes,you can set the holds before rm command and unset the holds after the rm command.

The objects cannot be modified or removed until the hold is removed

Comment: It is not possible to set a retention to a folder itself. Something needs to be inside of the folder and i just want to apply the retention to the empty folder, i have tried your answer and it did not worked.

Comment: This is because the folders not exists as storage atomic entity, folders are a representation in cloud storage as is mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects#object-considerations), for this reason you the holds only applies for objects

Comment: Got it, still not finding a solution, think it is impossible to do that! I mean, i can delete the content inside the bucket or part of it but i cannot prevent the deletion of a single empty folder via command!